# Combine/merge two separate image files of the same thing(newspaper page) taken in half

Tags: photos, macos

Is there a way of combining two photos of the same thing taken in half?

For example, i have two images of the same newspaper page taken in two halves in order to keep the focus and quality of the text to an acceptable level. Now, how do i merge these two photos into one seamless photo?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Unfortunately, your question is a little too broad as it's currently written. Reading [how to ask a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) may improve your chances of getting a good answer. For now, can you please [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/285135/edit) your question to clarify whether you're using a Mac, iPad, etc? Also, are you wanting to do this using a particular app, or are you wanting recommendations on what apps you could install to do this? Finally, be sure to include what version of macOS/iOS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of applications which will stitch images together, provided there is sufficient overlap. Calico is one I have used. Partly this depends on how the images are taken.

For simple tasks like this a manual process is probably better.

I use `GIMP`, importing the images into 2 layers and manually moving them until the match is "adequate".